# PyQt4 - closing a dialog window, exec_() not working

Tags: python, dialog, pyqt4

Trying to build a user interface using PyQt4. Got a dialog window that pops up, and I want it to do something then close, when 'Ok' is pressed. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it working - tried all sorts of combinations of Dialog.exec_(), Dialog.close(), self.exec_(), self.close(), emitting an 'accepted' signal to Dialog.accept, etc. So far, nothing has worked, and I'm not quite sure why. Here's the code for it:

Dialog window initialised as such;

```
def begin_grab(self):
    self.GrabIm=qtg.QDialog(self)
    self.GrabIm.ui=Ui_Dialog()
    self.GrabIm.ui.setupUi(self.GrabIm)
    self.GrabIm.show()
```

Dialog window;

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        ...
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), self.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def accept(self):
        if self.radioButton.isChecked()==True: #assume it is true
            #Call continuous grabber
            print "Grabbing continuously"
            Dialog.exec_() #Close it here
        else:
            #Call trigger server
            print "Grabbing triggered"
            self.exec_()
```

The main thing that keeps happening is either a message saying 'Dialog' is an unknown variable, in the accept() function, or if I use self.exec_() or similar it says exec_() is not a known attribute. If I try doing accept(self, Dialog), and put self.accept(Dialog) in the connect statement, it also crashes.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing it pretty wrong. You shouldn't modify the Qt Designer generated code (`Ui_Dialog`). You should subclass `QDialog` and define the `accept` there:

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # use new style signals
        self.ui.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.ui.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def accept(self):
        if self.ui.radioButton.isChecked(): # no need to do ==True
            #Call continuous grabber
            print "Grabbing continuously"
        else:
            #Call trigger server
            print "Grabbing triggered"
        super(MyDialog, self).accept()  # call the accept method of QDialog. 
                                           # super is needed 
                                           # since we just override the accept method
```

Then you initialize it as:

```
def begin_grab(self):
    self.GrabIm=MyDialog(self)
    self.GrabIm.exec_()  # exec_() for modal dialog
                           # show() for non-modal dialog
```

But looking at your code, I wouldn't do it that way. Let the dialog return with `accept/reject` and then do your conditional stuff in the caller (i.e. Main window):

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # use new style signals
        self.ui.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.ui.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
```

and the caller code:

```
def begin_grab(self):
    self.GrabIm=MyDialog(self)
    if self.GrabIm.exec_():  # this will be True if dialog is 'accept'ed, False otherwise
        if self.GrabIm.ui.radioButton.isChecked():
            #Call continuous grabber
            print "Grabbing continuously"
        else:
            #Call trigger server
            print "Grabbing triggered"
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you shouldn't change the Qt Designer generated code? I mean, it seems to work fine even if I do change it, so is there some technical reason I'm missing as to why I shouldn't do it? But regardless, this is a great answer, I hadn't thought of doing the actions if exec_() returned true or false. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveLewis: You _can_ change the Designer generated code of course. If you don't break it, it'll work perfectly fine but it is not meant to be modified by hand. Designer generated code is meant to be 'plugged-in' to your actual MainWindow/Dialog/Widget subclass via `setupUi`. You see, your `Ui_Dialog` is not a subclass of `QDialog`. That's why you couldn't do `self.exec_()` since `exec_()` is a method of `QDialog`. [This link](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html) might give you a basic idea for using Designer code.

Comment: By the way, you can also forget about Designer and code all the GUI part by hand (which is what I prefer). And Qt is pretty friendly in that sense.

Comment: Alright, thanks very much! Yeah, I usually prefer coding by hand, but I'm short of time on this project and relatively new to Qt (been using Tkinter before now. Shudder.), so I just used the designer for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

You can re implement closeEvent which will help you to do some process before Dialog exit

```
def closeEvent(self,event):
   print "I am here"
   event.accept()
```